# error while putting mapped values in arguments in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Good Day!!

I was searching for some solution on my ansible playbook where I want to run an application inbuilt .sh script with arguments and corresponding mapped values.

Below is the command which I can successfully execute in terminal window.

I tried with shell, command and script modules, but no luck..

`./repotools-jts.sh -setup repositoryURL=https://myappurl:9443/jts responsefile=response.properties adminUserId=mydomainID adminPassword=passwd`

Comment: can you show how you were doing it in ansible?

Comment: here is my play.       ---

- name: Run JTS SETUP
  hosts: IHS
  tasks:
    - name: Commandline JTS SETUP from Response file
      script: /opt/IBM/605CLM/JazzTeamServer/server/repotools-jts.sh -setup repositoryURL=https://myappurl:9443/jts parametersFile=/opt/IBM/605CLM/JazzTeamServer/server/response_lat.properties adminUserId=mydomainid adminPassword=mypassword

Comment: it is not formatted. Can you put your code in the question with code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

here is my play.       ---

- name: Run JTS SETUP
  hosts: IHS
  tasks:

  - name: Commandline JTS SETUP from Response file
    script: /opt/IBM/605CLM/JazzTeamServer/server/repotools-jts.sh -setup repositoryURL=https://myappurl:9443/jts parametersFile=/opt/IBM/605CLM/JazzTeamServer/server/response_lat.properties adminUserId=mydomainid adminPassword=mypassword